# Return more than 2 duplicates in each sublist (2d list)

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a large 2d list that has duplicates in some sublists. I would like to return 2 or more duplicates and  return the duplicates first if impossible. For instance,

```
Df =[[2,3,5,20],[5,10,20,10],[4,13,15,15,17,34,17],[33,34,15,21],[12,16,24,32,12,33,24]]
```

I would like my result like this:

```
Df2 = [[15,17,4,13,34],[12,24,16,32,33]]
```

I have tried this code below but I only want it to return the duplicates that has 2 or more duplicates.

```
res = [t for t in Df if len(t) > len(set(t))]
```

Comment: You can use Python's `collections module`, specifically `Counter`, which simplifies the process of counting occurrences.

Comment: How do I do that. Do u know a code?

Comment: Df is my original dataframe and Df2 is my desire result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` from the `collections` module to count occurrences of each element within the sublists. Then, filter out those sublists that have duplicates

```
from collections import Counter

Df = [[2, 3, 5, 20], [5, 10, 20, 10], [4, 13, 15, 15, 17, 34, 17], [33, 34, 15, 21], [12, 16, 24, 32, 12, 33, 24]]

# Count occurrences of elements in each sublist
counts = [Counter(sublist) for sublist in Df]

# Find sublists with duplicates and at least 2 duplicates
duplicates = [[elem for elem, count in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)] 
              for count in counts if sum(val > 1 for val in count.values()) >= 2]

print(duplicates)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[15, 17, 4, 13, 34], [12, 24, 16, 32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Counter` from `collections` as suggested, it is not too hard to filter out lists where there are two counts > 1 like so:

```py
from collections import Counter
Df =[[2,3,5,20],[5,10,20,10],[4,13,15,15,17,34,17],[33,34,15,21],[12,16,24,32,12,33,24]]
res = [list(set(t)) for t in Df if len([x for x in Counter(t).values() if x > 1]) >= 2]
print(res)
```

This prints `[[34, 4, 13, 15, 17], [32, 33, 12, 16, 24]]` on my computer. The lists will have an arbitrary order.